# Is it possible to calulate the highest value of a none quadratic function

Tags: functions

I am new to math and trying to learn some new things. I couldn't find an answer on the internet and I am not sure if it is possible so maybe you guys know it. I want to calculate which x I need to use to get the highest value y

$$y=b-\frac k{a+.997x}-x$$

The following is known:
$$a = 119587
,\quad b = 120092,\quad
k = a \times b$$

Is that even possible? and if so, how do you calculate it. The values for a, b are just made up.

Edit: I made mistake in the method, it was as well with a minus 'x' at the end.

So with excel I can run the method for different x inputs and you can see that the answer is close to 73, but I am looking at the precise number and more important on how to calculate it;) Love to learn it! Or where I can find the information (the name)

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 70 | 0,04383687711 |
| 71 | 0,04387116904 |
| 72 | 0,04388879632 |
| 73 | 0,04388975941 |
| 74 | 0,04387405873 |

Comment: This is hard to read.  do you mean $y=b-\frac k{a+.997x}-.004$?   If so, note that, as $x\to -\frac a{.997}$ from the right, your $y$ becomes arbitrarily large.

Comment: That is what I mean, Not sure how I can edit it to your format.

Comment: I've done it for you.  For future reference, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look and thanks for updating it!

Comment: What is meant by saying values of a,b,k are "just fictional"?

Comment: that a and b can be different values, just made up for this example. I will change that in the post

Comment: If you don't know calculus, you'll have to use technology to find the maximum.

Comment: @SeanRoberson This can be solved without calculus (see my answer), although some witty algebraic manipulation is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow $x$ to take negative values, there is no maximum (see lulu's comment).

If you are looking for $x$ positive, observe that $$\frac{(a-\sqrt{.997 k} + .997 x)^2}{.997(a+.997x)} \ge 0$$

From this follows (after some algebraic manipulations) that

$$b-\frac{k}{a+.997x}-x\le b+\frac{a-2\sqrt{.997 k}}{c}$$

and equality is achieved when $\displaystyle x = \frac{\sqrt{.997k}-a}{.997}$

So the maximum with the values you have for $a$, $b$ and $k$ is achieved in $$x= \frac{\sqrt{.997 k}-a}{.997} = 72.5577935\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for! And yes x already positive

Comment: @Klokje Then you could accept my answer.